# Negative arrays python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to make negative this array but the output it's empty, I don't know if there's a function that makes negative an array

```
max=[5,4]

min=max*-1
```

Comment: it would work if you would use `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` instead of standard list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
m = [5,4]
n = [-i for i in m]
```

Also, avoid using 'min' and 'max' as variable names in python, as they are keywords.